# Facebook Graph API returns blank array instead of Page Events data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been accessing my events information for the past few months without trouble, making a Graph API call to /{page-id}/events using v7.0. Today I updated the token to include access to more pages and now, suddenly, every call for the events data returns a data response like this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I have a valid access token. Previously it showed my page events but now nothing appears. I've double checked and my page has a lot of active events.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the api docs do not show the events endpoint anymore, i assume it is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#edges

Comment: Hi @luschn, thanks for your answer. I thought about that, but checking the last deprecations in developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/312249250086350 that one doesn't appear... Also, if it's deprecated, how come they let us choose it as a field when using the Graph API? Shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ says, _“Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners.”_, and has been saying that for quite a while already. It might be that you still had access with your existing token due to some sort of glitch, and that generating a new token has “fixed” that now.